# How to check throw error on response in node js when my query result rowCount is 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

If my rowcount is o i need to send on res as failed. If my rowcount is
 1 i need to send res status as success. Kindly help me out. when i
 tried to take print (client.query) its coming as json(result on
 attached image)

[image]

```
var query = client.query("select * from pp_user_profile where email_id  = '"+req.query.email_id+"' and user_password= '"+req.query.user_password+"'");

    console.log(client.query);
    query.on("end", function (result) {
    if (result.length > 0) {
      if (result)
        console.log("Test:" + result);
        res.write('Failed');
    }
    else{
        console.log(result);            
        client.end();
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write('Success');
        res.end();  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the if...else condition to this way.

```
if(result.rowCount === 1){
   // your code goes here
}
else{
   // your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your requirement properly then u should have the code as follows:

```
var query = client.query("select * from pp_user_profile where email_id  = '"+req.query.email_id+"' and user_password= '"+req.query.user_password+"'");


    query.on("end", function (result) {
    if (result.rows.length === 0) {
      client.end();
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write('Failed');
        res.end(); 
    }
    else{         
        client.end();
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write('Success');
        res.end();  
    }
```

Comment: @subburaj..just if i get 1 records on my query. i need to send response status as success. if i get 0 the user is not found on my database so i will send failure response.